# UPDATE psql table with calculated value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Table A:

```
id | dob
```

Table B:

```
id | type
```

I want to calculate age from A.dob and based on that I want to update B.type, I tried following but it is giving me an error.

```
UPDATE B
SET     B.type   =  CASE  
                        WHEN AGE <= 16 THEN 'C' 
                        WHEN AGE>25 and age<=40 THEN 'Y' 
                        WHEN AGE>40 THEN 'O' 
                    END 

from AGE as ( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(now(),A.dob)) ), A inner join B on A.id=B.id 
where A.dob is not null;
```

Comment: A rule of thumb for relational database: do not store data that can easily be derived from existing data. Create a view with that "type" information, then you do not need to update the table every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
update b
    set type = (case when age <= 16 then 'C' 
                     when age > 25 and age <= 40 then 'Y' 
                     when age > 40 then 'O' 
                end) 
from (select a.*, extact(year from age(now(), a.dob)) as age
      from a
     ) a
where a.id = b.id and a.age is not null;
```

Notes:

- Your logic has no type for 17 to 24 year-olds.
- Don't repeat the table being updated in the `FROM` clause.  That is not how Postgres works.
- The `JOIN` conditions -- alas -- go in the `WHERE` clause.
- This uses a subquery to calculate `age`.
- I figure you might as well test for `age` not being `NULL` rather than the base column.